# Python - BeautifulSoup pulling values value from input

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the CSRFToken from a webpage. My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.clos19.com/en-gb/login')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('input', type='hidden'))
```

The response from the terminal is below:

```
[<input name="CSRFToken" type="hidden" value="790bf524-642c-4679-a036-8f126fe14940"/>]
```

How do I only get the value 790bf524-642c-4679-a036-8f126fe14940 to be outputted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.clos19.com/en-gb/login')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('input', type='hidden')["value"])
```

By adding ["value"], the printed output is only the csrf token.

Answer (score 1):

```
for value in soup.find_all('input', type='hidden'):
    print(value.get('value'))
```

or

```
print(soup.find('input', type='hidden').get('value'))
```